# How to run a PHP script on a shared hosting server from cPanel?

Tags: php, cpanel, personal-website, script

I'm trying to install Tinyboard (`http://tinyboard.net/`) on a shared hosting, I uploaded all of the files in a single folder, now I should run `install.php`, but I have no clue where that can be accomplished from the cPanel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You navigate to the `install.php` file in the browser.

eg. `http://example.com/install.php`

In fact, this is exactly what the instructions state on the page you linked to:

> 2. Navigate to `install.php` in your web browser and follow the prompts.

Note that you should delete these install files afterwards (if they are not deleted for you), as it's an obvious security risk leaving these files lying around!

Comment: All I receive is this error message  http://error.webfreaks.pw/

Comment: Even changing permissions to execute the file won't hold any result

Comment: I don't see an error message?

Comment: now I succeded to start the install.php, but I get an "ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons"

Comment: Presumably that is a "Warning", not a statement? It's possible that your host has disabled `ini_set()` (a PHP function) in the server config.

Comment: damn. do you think this will work it out?  http://forums.glowhost.com/knowledge-base/how-fix-ini_set-has-been-disabled-security-reasons-2503.html

Comment: I think that will depend on your host. The `disable_functions` directive is not something that is intended to be user-configurable on a shared hosting environment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30029/discussion-between-ed0-and-w3d).